# Uploading files to Google Cloud Storage using JSON API, Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to figure out how to use the `JSON API` in Android to upload images to `Google Cloud Storage` but the documentation for doing so seems to be very limited.

The problem I am having I believe is getting the correct API key authentication. The images that are uploaded are images that are considered public but only public to the users of my app so reading [Authorize Requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey) documentation says that I do not need to provide an OAuth key for public data and I can just send an API key

> Public API access: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token
>   must send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API
>   access, quota, and reports.

so I went to my console created a key `(API Manager/Credentials/Create Credentials/API Key)` from my `SHA1` of my debug and production keystore's.

these API keys are correct because they are used with other google services like `google sign-in` and they work fine.

When I try to make a request to start a resumable upload this is what I do

```
String sUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable&name="+mImgName;
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","AIzaSyDT....");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type","image/png");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length",String.valueOf(fileSize));
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

however I get back `Error 401 Unauthorized` so I am assuming it is a problem with the key I am sending.

I also saw at the end of the `Authorize Requests` document that it states I can put my key as a parameter of the request url

> After you have an API key, your application can append the query
>   parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

so I dont know if I am suppose to do that or have the `Authorization` property set in the request or both?

So is the key I created the wrong type of key or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You can use an API key for downloading public objects. But unless your bucket is enabled for public write (you probably don't want to do that), then you still need to use OAuth for uploads to the bucket.

Comment: My app is suppose to allow users to be able to view/store images publicly without having them sign in. They have limited access to certain images based on a key that gets generated by my app (that key is then shared with other users) and anyone with that key can view the images associated with that key. 

@jterrace so are you saying there is no was for a user to have read/write privileges to a bucket without having them login?

Comment: You probably want to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs).

Comment: Sure. I'll add it as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking up about Signed URL's that @jterrace suggested I found that since I need a resumable url I can just use that without client authentication

> If your users are only uploading resources (writing) to an
>   access-controlled bucket, you can use the resumable uploads
>   functionality of Google Cloud Storage, and avoid signing URLs or
>   requiring a Google account. In a resumable upload scenario, your
>   (server-side) code authenticates and initiates an upload to Google
>   Cloud Storage without actually uploading any data. The initiation
>   request returns an session URI, which can then be used in a client
>   request to upload the data. The client request does not need to be
>   signed because the session URI, in effect, acts as an authentication
>   token.

So what I do is I let my `App Engine` backend create the resumable url and then pass that along to my client and I get the auth token on the backend with this

```
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control");
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes); 
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken.getAccessToken());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API key for downloading public objects.

But unless your bucket is enabled for public write, which you generally don't want to do, then you still need to use authentication for uploads to the bucket.

In your case, I think you probably want to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs).

Comment: What I ended up doing was have me App Engine backend create a resumable url since that is what I need anyway and then pass that url to the client. that url is acts as an authentication token